# AppEngine URL Fetch > 60 seconds

Tags: java, google-app-engine, urlfetch

My AppEngine project retrieves XML data from a particular link using the GAE URL fetch API. I have used the sample from [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/urlfetch/#Java_Fetching_URLs_with_java_net) except that it looks like this:

```
InputStream stream;
URLConnection connection = new URL(url).openConnection();
connection.setConnectTimeout(0);
connection.setReadTimeout(0);
stream = connection.getInputStream();
```

This takes more than 60 seconds (max allowed by the API) and hence causes a DeadlineExceededException. Using TaskQueues for the purpose is also not an option as mentioned [here](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log&groupby=&sort=&id=10470).

Is there any other way someone might have achieved this until now?

Thanks!

Comment: If the request takes more than 60 seconds the problem probably lies with the server you're retrieving the xml from

Comment: Can you do a test fetch yourself using e.g. curl, to rule out or confirm server problems as Tim said?

Comment: Hi @Tim there aren't any problems with the source server itself. Here's the link: muc2014.communitymashup.net/x3/mashup

Answer (score 0):

Task Queues can be active longer than the AppEngine automatic scaling request response deadline of 1 minute. On automatic scaling, a task can run for 10 minutes. On basic or manual scaling, it can run for 24 hours. See the docs [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/#Python_Instance_scaling_and_class). (Note that the language python is actually not related to the material - the same is true for Java on GAE, Go, PHP, as well).

Finally, I have to echo what was said by the other users - the latency is almost certainly caused by the endpoint of your URL fetch, not by the network or app engine. You can also check this for sure by looking at your App Engine log lines for the failing requests. The cpu_millis field tells you how long the actual process GAE-side worked on the request, while the millis field will be the total time for the request. If the total time is much higher than the cpu time, it means the cost was elsewhere in the network.

It might be related to bandwidth exhaustion of multiple connections relative to the endpoint's limited resources. If the endpoint is `muc2014.communitymashup.net/x3/mashup` as you added in a comment, it might help to know that at the time I posted this comment, approx `1424738921` in unix time, the average latency (including full response, not just time to response beginning) on that endpoint was ~6 seconds, although that could feasibly go up to >60s given heavy load if no scaling system is set up for the endpoint. The observed latency is already quite high, but it might vary according to what kind of work needs to be done server-side, what volume of requests/data is being handled, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lied in the stream being used by a function from the EMF library which took a lot of time (wasn't the case previously). 
Rather, loading the contents from the URL into a StringBuilder, converting it to a separate InputStream and passing that to the function worked. All this being done in a cron job.

Comment: So your original question was inaccurate? You determined that it was some (un-shown) other code consuming the inputstream that *actually* caused the timeout? I had thought you would have done the basic profiling or determined whether a timeout occurring in a function would be due to this or that line in the function as opposed to another... This is why you were unable to find help. I hope in future you ask a question with *all* the relevant information so that people can help determine what's happening and maybe point you in the right direction sooner.